# Not able to connect to MySQL using Java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-workbench

I am using the below code to connect to MySQL

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;


public class connectMysql {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Connection conn = null;
        try{
            conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//test","root","admin");
            if(conn!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connected successfully");
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Not connected");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The username: root, password: admin, Hostname: localhost, Port: 3306.
I get the output as "Not connected".

[Edits] Now I Stack Trace and see that error is 'Unknown database '/test'. But I do have a schema named test. Is the schema same as the database?

Everything is same as this. But I don't seem to get connected to the DB. 
Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: please print 'e' in the Exception block. It will give you a hint

Comment: @Tammy thanks for that. I added that and get the error that i mentioned in the description.

Comment: @Josephine no need of double slash in front of the text
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"

Comment: @Tammy thanks. It works now. The double slash was the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check all the drivers are available in the Library

Check for the port number, Username and password(case Sensitive)

if every thing is correct then

use the below code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // Setup the connection with the DB
  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "username", "password"); 
  statement = con.createStatement();
```

Comment: I added your code and get this output in the console: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 statement cannot be resolved to a variable
 connect cannot be resolved

 at connectMysql.main(connectMysql.java:10)"

Comment: @Josephine sorry its con not connect change the last line as statement = con.createStatement()

Answer (score 2):

Why you have double slash // before your database name in your connection string

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//test","root","admin"
```

Change it to

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","admin"
```